# How to run multiple commands in single line in geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, console

Can I run multiple commands at once in geth's JavaScript console?

Can I do something like `> api1.command1() && api2.command2("arg2") && api1.command3()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you separate them with `;` ?

Comment: Yes! This works too :) Since this is the closest to what I'm looking for, I'm going to accept this answer, but thanks for all the help.

Comment: Note that separating with `;` does not work fully. If you try `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x9535b2e7faaba5288511d89341d94a38063a349b"), "ether"); web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x88a80b35014fe7c33b4568cb818f2e16ba799b23"), "ether");`, only a single result `1.01029574` is returned.

There are ways to get around it, eg: `var v1=web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x9535b2e7faaba5288511d89341d94a38063a349b"), "ether"); var v2=web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x88a80b35014fe7c33b4568cb818f2e16ba799b23"), "ether");console.log(v1 + " " + v2);` will return the result `17.350627444329232008 1.01029574`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I run my multiple command scripts in Linux and OS/X.

I've created a file `$HOME/bin/multipleCommands.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT:" | sed "s/RESULT: //"

var balance1 = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x9535b2e7faaba5288511d89341d94a38063a349b"), "ether");
console.log("RESULT: balance1=" + balance1);
var balance2 = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x88a80b35014fe7c33b4568cb818f2e16ba799b23"), "ether");
console.log("RESULT: balance2=" + balance2);

EOF
```

I then set the executable bit for this file using the command

```
chmod 700 $HOME/bin/multipleCommands.sh
```

I run the following command to produce the output:

```
$HOME/bin/multipleCommands.sh
balance1=17.431747444329232008
balance2=1.042500854
```

In Ubuntu, the `$HOME/bin` subdirectory will be added to your `$PATH` once you log out and then log in. You can then run commands in the `$HOME/bin` subdirectory without specifying the `$HOME/bin/` prefix to your command. So the following will work:

```
multipleCommands.sh
balance1=17.431747444329232008
balance2=1.042500854
```

If you are running Windows, the commands above should work if you install the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) shell.

While you are writing your script and debugging your `geth` commands, use the following statement in your script file so you can see the progress of the `geth` statements being executed:

```
# geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT:" | sed "s/RESULT: //"
geth attach << EOF
```

instead of:

```
geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT:" | sed "s/RESULT: //"
```

Comment: This is really cool ! But while debugging, when I run `geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT:" | sed "s/RESULT: //"` I can't see what is executed, I get an infinite number of `>` until I `^C`. What should I do next ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - use the `loadScript(...)` in the other answer if you need to use the console. Use the `geth attach << EOF` if you don't need to use the console and are still debugging. Then use the `geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT:" | sed "s/RESULT: //"` when you have finished debugging and just have to run the command repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /path/to/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`. The path wasn't initially correct, so I changed `geth attach<<EOF` to `geth attach ipc:/correct/path/geth.ipc`, and I get the same error, but with the correct path (I think). Makes me remember why I had given up on `attach` after I discovered it...

Comment: What. I found the correct path with `find / -name "eth.ipc"` but now find returns nothing. Did it get deleted by running attach ?

Comment: Ooooh ok I understood now, I feel really stupid. You need an running instance of Geth to attach to, and geth.ipc exists only when geth is running. This in incredibly useful !

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to put them in a JavaScript file and use

```
LoadScript ('/path/myjs.js').
```

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#loadscript